# Diophantine equation of a factorial type

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

I'm interested in nontrivial solutions of Diophantine equations of the type
$$a^2b^3 =  \frac{c!}{(c-k)!} $$

For various values of k fixed, and of course $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z^+}$

Does anyone have any insight into this type of equation or a good reference for further reading? My search is being swamped by irrelevant results.

Edit: I changed n to c to emphasize that I am looking for a,b,c that solve this equation. Thus for k= 1, the equation becomes $a^2b^3 = c$, which clearly has infinity many solutions.

Comment: Look up Shorey Tijdeman and related on perfect powers of (products of) consecutive integers.  It will get you a step closer, and most likely your results of interest will reference their work. Laishram has related material as well.  Gerhard "Is Researching Sylvester And Schur" Paseman, 2020.07.25.

Comment: @Gerhard squarefull is far from perfect power, so it's not clear to me how much closer Shorey & Tijdeman will get us.

Comment: No, but if anyone has published on this problem recently,  I can't think of any other paper they would reference.  Gerhard "Maybe You Know Of One?" Paseman, 2020.07.25.

Answer (score 3):

You may already know this, but numbers of the form $a^2b^3$ are called *powerful numbers*. A closely related question that might provide information on your question is to ask for binomial coefficients that are powerful. A Google search of "powerful number" and "binomial coefficient" brought up the following paper of Granville:

On the scarcity of powerful binomial coefficients

Andrew Granville

[https://dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/powerful.pdf](https://dms.umontreal.ca/%7Eandrew/PDF/powerful.pdf)

He proves that there are only finitely many powerful binomial coefficients, contingent on the *abc* conjecture.

Comment: Is there literature on consecutive powerful numbers, or intervals containing many powerful numbers?  Gerhard "Are Numbers More Powerful Together?" Paseman, 2020.07.25.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman  Here's a reference with some information on that question: POWERFUL  NUMBERS  IN  SHORT  INTERVALS, JEAN-MARIE  DE  KONINCK,  FLORIAN  LUCA  AND  IGOR  E.   SHPARLINSKI,  BULL.   AUSTRAL.   MATH.  SOC.  71  (2005)

Comment: It is conjectured that there are never three consecutive powerful numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is exactly the type of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in extensions to the Sylvester Schur theorem, which by your constraints shows that c is bigger than k^2 as the set of consecutive integers in the product must have a single multiple of q^2 for some prime q bigger than k. A paper of Saradha and Shorey from 2003, Almost Squares and Factorizations in Consecutive Integers, shows the sparsity of solutions to your equation where k-1 of the numbers on the right hand side multiply to a square.  This may be useful for you in a citation search .

Gerhard "Not Quite Almost Powerful Numbers" Paseman, 2020.07.25.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest interesting case of $k=2$ reduces to a family of Pell equations paramaterized by $b$:
$$(2c-1)^2 - b^3(2a)^2 = 1.$$
This gives infinitely many solutions.

For example, for $b=2$, we have a series of solutions indexed by $n$:
$$c_n + a_n\sqrt{8} = \frac{(17+6\sqrt{8})^n+1}2.$$
Numerical values of $c_n$ are listed in [OEIS A055792](https://oeis.org/A055792).

Comment: Also, given powerful numbers m and m+1, we have 4m(m+1) and (2m+1)^2 also powerful.  Gerhard "Finally Remembered That Contest Problem" Paseman, 2020.07.25.

Comment: @Gerhard, yes, where the trick is finding consecutive powerful numbers. Numbers $n$ such that $n$ and $n+1$ are both powerful are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A060355

Comment: Ah. So you know about 25*27 and 26*26 already.  Gerhard "No More Element Of Surprise" Paseman, 2020.07.25.